# Large arrays crash the arduino

Tags: array, debugging, progmem, sketch-size

I have three large `PROGMEM` arrays, in order to store musical notes for a song. One array is the notes, one is the note durations, and one is the pause after the note.

The first array is an `int` one and the other two are `floats.` The program works, but after a specific number of elements, the arduino crashes. Meaning, I upload the program without problems, but the device does nothing.

When I have 227 elements (in all three arrays) obviously, the program works. If I increase the number  of elements to 228, nothing happens when I upload...

When the IDE says `avrdude: 10606 bytes of flash verified` then everything works. When the size gets increased to `10616`, everything crashes. Is this normal behaviour?

**EDIT:** The code is trivial, the only important part of the code is this:

```
int number_of_stored_values_in_MelodyArray = sizeof(Crash_Melody) / sizeof(int);
int Melody_Array[number_of_stored_values_in_MelodyArray];
memcpy_P(Melody_Array, Crash_Melody, sizeof Melody_Array);
```

I am using `memcpy_P()` in order to copy the arrays from `PROGMEM` to RAM.
I do this for the int and the two float arrays. With 221 elements in each array, I guess I am out of RAM.

The reason I have an array for the pause as well, is because I am using an online midi to tone() converter and that is the format that it uses. So I have to stick to that format.

I think if I did the assignment incrementally - like for example copy only 20 elements from the array, play the song, then repeat until the end, I would have no problem.

Is there a way for `memcpy_P()` to specify not the whole array to copy, but index them? Does it take a starting index value?

**EDIT 2:**
This is a snippet of code after trying Edgar Bonnet's approach.

```
int number_of_stored_values_in_MelodyArray = sizeof(My_Melody) / sizeof(int);
for (int i = 0; i < number_of_stored_values_in_MelodyArray; i++)
{
  int note = pgm_read_word(&My_Melody[i]);
  float duration = pgm_read_word(&My_noteDurations[i]);
  float pause_duration = pgm_read_word(&My_Delay[i]);
  playMelodyExtended2(note, duration, pause_duration, number_of_stored_values_in_MelodyArray, 10, 400);
}

int playMelodyExtended2(int melody, float noteDuration, float pauseDuration, int number_of_notes, int music_pin, int delay_var)
{
  for (int thisNote = 0; thisNote < number_of_notes; thisNote++)
  {
    tone( music_pin, melody, noteDuration );
    delay( pauseDuration );
    noTone(music_pin);
  }

  delay(delay_var);
}
```

**EDIT 3:**
This is the newest iteration of the code:

```
 int number_of_stored_values_in_MelodyArray = sizeof(My_Melody) / sizeof(int);
 for (int i = 0; i < number_of_stored_values_in_MelodyArray; i++)
 {
    int note = pgm_read_byte_near(&My_Melody[i]);
    note << 8;
    note += pgm_read_byte_near(&My_Melody[i+1]);
    float duration = pgm_read_float_near(&My_noteDurations[i]);
    uint16_t pause_duration = pgm_read_byte_near(&My_Delay[i]);
    pause_duration << 8;
    pause_duration += pgm_read_byte_near(&My_Delay[i+1]);
    playMelodyExtended2(note, duration, pause_duration, number_of_stored_values_in_MelodyArray, 10, 400);
  }

int playMelodyExtended2(int melody, float noteDuration, uint16_t pauseDuration, int number_of_notes, int music_pin, int delay_var)
{
  for (int thisNote = 0; thisNote < number_of_notes; thisNote++)
  {
    tone( music_pin, melody, noteDuration );
    delay( pauseDuration );
    // stop the tone playing:
    noTone(music_pin);
  }

  delay(delay_var);
}
```

Comment: why are duration and pauses represented by floats? ... they are not floats in music notation

Comment: What Arduino are you using? Could you share your code (without the array contents)?

Comment: also share the messages in the arduino IDE ... copy the text and paste into your question ... do  NOT use a screenshot ... do not put in a comment

Comment: the three arrays can be of type `byte` ... you only need two arrays ... a pause is just an unvoiced note ... use value 0 for pauses

Comment: As long as the last message of the compile and link tells you that you don't fill the flash over 100%, everything is fine. Anyway, please [edit] your question and provide a minimal, reproducible, and complete example. It can consists of just a big enough array and empty `setup()` and `loop()`. Add the output log.

Comment: Which Arduino? This is kind-of important. Assuming you have 32k of programmable memory (for example, on the Uno) then 2280 bytes of array should not crash it. I would be wondering about your code, frankly. The code you didn't post.

Comment: `When the IDE says avrdude: 10606 bytes of flash verified then everything works. When the size gets increased to 10616, everything crashes. Is this normal behaviour?` No, of course not.

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: `Is there a way for memcpy_P() to specify not the whole array to copy, but index them?`  yes, well you could do: `memcpy_P(&Melody_Array[10], Crash_Melody, 10);` to get 10 bytes, but what Edgar Bonet said is a much better solution. Just access each note one at a time. There is no point in making the code complex by getting chunks of notes.

Comment: With your "Edit 2": Looks like the wrong number of bytes are being read for your floats or some number format conversion issue produces basically random numbers for your durations. Try `pgm_read_float` for reading the floats.

Comment: @orithena Thanks! Tried it as well, but now I hear a periodic beeping. All the beeps and pauses between are the same... I also tried `pgm_read_byte_near()` for the `int` variable, but with the same results...

Comment: @user1584421 This sounds as if there are some conversion issues. By using the `pgm_read_*` methods, you are basically saying "Read n bytes from Progmem and just put the bits into the variable". That means _you_ need to _know_ which bitsize the values are in your Progmem array, how many bits are read by the `pgm_read_*` methods, how many bits are in the target variable and whether it is a signed int, unsigned int or IEEE768-formatted float. Try to output the numbers (Serial.println as first line in playMelodyExtended2, outputting all arguments) and compare them to your input arrays.

Comment: @user1584421 It may also be a good idea to use the type `int16_t`, `uint16_t`, `int32_t` or `uint32_t` instead of a plain `int`. `int` actually is an alias, denoting the "standard int" for the CPU/platform you're compiling for; using one of the types above, you'll always know the bitsize of your variable. But this is a problem far off your original question, so a new question might be a good idea here (please also post the code that creates the PROGMEM array, as there might be some clues in there).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the edited version of your question, you wrote:

> I am using `memcpy_P()` in order to copy the arrays from `PROGMEM` to
> RAM.

The whole purpose of `PROGMEM` is to **avoid having to store the data in
RAM**. If you copy the arrays to RAM, you are defeating `PROGMEM`. Your
Arduino has much more Flash than RAM, and it will crash if you eat up
all the RAM. This is why the `PROGMEM` optimization is valuable whenever
you have large arrays of constant data.

The proper way to use those arrays is to copy to RAM one element at a
time: get the data for the next note you have to play, then play it,
then move to the next one. E.g.:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < melody_length; i++) {
    int note = pgm_read_word(&Crash_Melody[i]);
    // etc...
}
```

Copying small chunks to RAM, as you suggest in your question, would make
the code more complex and add absolutely no value.

---

**Edit**: In the second edit of your question, you have this:

```cpp
float duration = pgm_read_word(&My_noteDurations[i]);
```

What this does is:

- read the first two bytes of `My_noteDurations[i]` (which is a
  four-byte quantity, thus you are truncating it)
- interpret that as an integer (which it is not)
- convert that to `float`

The result will have little to do with the original number. The correct
way to read a float from `PROGMEM` is to use `pgm_read_float()`.

That being said, I see now that you use this number as a parameter for
`delay()`. Given that this function takes an integer, there is no point
in storing the delay as a float. This will only add a (somewhat costly)
float-to-integer conversion to your program, with no added benefit.
Also, since the delays are likely to be less than 65 seconds, a
16-bit unsigned integer should be enough.

Further down, you have this:

```cpp
for (int thisNote = 0; thisNote < number_of_notes; thisNote++)
{
  tone(music_pin, melody, noteDuration);
  delay(pauseDuration);
  noTone(music_pin);
}
```

I fail to see the purpose of this loop. You are repeating **each note**
a number of times that is equal to the total number of notes in the
song. Why?

---

**Answer to edit 3**: there are a few issues I can see in this version
of the code.

1. Consistency of the data types: in the previous version, it looked
   like the pause durations were floats. Now they are integers. You have
   to make sure you use the `pgm_read_*()` function suitable for the
   actual data type of the array.
2. Reading by bytes: there is no point in reading a 16-bit integer one
   byte at a time: use `pgm_read_word()` to read it all at once. Reading
   byte by byte only makes the code more complex and increases the
   chances of bugs. In fact, your way of reconstructing the numbers is
   buggy.
3. The loop in `playMelodyExtended2()` makes no sense to me. Please, try
   removing it.

Here is what I suggest at this point:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < number_of_stored_values_in_MelodyArray; i++)
{
    int note = pgm_read_word(&My_Melody[i]);
    float duration = pgm_read_float(&My_noteDurations[i]);
    uint16_t pause_duration = pgm_read_word(&My_Delay[i]);
    tone(10, note, duration);
    delay(pause_duration);
}
```

This snippet makes some assumptions about the rest of your code, and
specifically about the way your arrays are defined. If these assumptions
are incorrect, this will not work. Thus, I second @orithena's comment
and urge you to post a full, testable version of you sketch (three notes
would be enough).

Comment: Thanks! I tried your approach but it didn't work. I have posted the code in my question. All I hear is a constant buzz.

Comment: Thanks Edgar!  I tried `pgm_read_float()` as well, but all I heard was a periodic beeping. All the beeps and pauses between are the same... I also tried `pgm_read_byte_near()` for the `int` variable, but with the same results. I will try to trim the float array, since `delay()` receives only ints... As for why the code is like that.... Yes, I am iterating for every number of notes in the melody. I have found an online midi to `tone()` converter that outputs three arrays. The pitch, the note duration and the delay. So I created this function in order to handle it. This works but I am out of RAM

Comment: @user1584421: This iteration makes no sense. Try playing each note only once.

Comment: But how it should be done? This works. Like I said, the website the performs the conversion gives three arrays for each given note. Pitch, duration and delay....

Comment: However, since that function works, and its compatible with the format, why change it? There is an error probably, in how I parse that data from `PROGMEM`. I updated the question with what I last tried.

Comment: @user1584421 Yes, it works, but probably not in the way you want it to. If your array has 1283 notes, you call `playMelodyExtended2` with `number_of_notes = 1283`. Then this for loop plays the first note 1283 times. It then returns, the next note/duration/delay is read, then `playMelodyExtended2` is called again for that second note. And it plays that second note 1283 times. Repeat until all 1283 notes are played 1283 times _each_. Your Edit 3 also does not fix that.

Comment: I also tried the first approach, with `memcpy_P`, but I made the delay[] array as `uint16_t`. And this works, but then it suddenly stops.... So it is better, because with the original approach, it didn't play at all. But now, it still does not play the whole melody.

Comment: @orithena I get it now. I should remove the for loop inside the `playMelodyExtended2()` function. EDIT: I just did, and it does not work as intended.

Comment: @user1584421 Yes. You then may also remove the argument `number_of_notes` Or, alternatively, always call `playMelodyExtended2` with `number_of_notes = 1`, if you need that argument in the future for other purposes.

Comment: @user1584421 Then it is time to finally post full code, especially the actual declaration of the PROGMEN arrays (the first three values of each array would suffice). Also, add that debugging output of the actual values in `playMelodyExtended2` I mentioned yesterday, compare them to your input arrays, and after that, we may be able to help you further.

Comment: @EdgarBonet Thank you so much! This was it!

Comment: @orithena The last edit in this answer worked! My code was included in my question, it was what I posted. The PROGMEM definitions were trivial. `const int My_Melody[] PROGMEM =
{
  55,
  //...
};

const float My_noteDurations[] PROGMEM =
{
  200.7139,
  //....
};

const uint16_t My_Delay[] PROGMEM =
{
  214,
  //...
};`